# Variable thymeleaf a javascript y de javascript a Controller

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, controller, thymeleaf

necesito pasar una variable del Model en thymeleaf a javascript. Desde javascript necesito pasarla como parte de una url hacia el controller. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Tengo algo así pero no funciona:

En un `<button>` en Thymeleaf:

```
th:onclick="método('[[(${id})]]')"
```

En javascript:

```
function método(id) {
    var neededId = id;
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/urlDeController/neededId",
            type: "GET",
    ....
```

Y finalmente en Controller (java):

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/urlDeController/{neededId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Integer iniciarOp(@PathVariable("neededId") int neededId ...
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo para que funcione? Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

No estás usando el parámetro de la función:

```
function método(id) {
    var neededId = id;
    $.ajax(
        {
            //esto es un string normal, se manda tal cual
            url: "/urlDeController/neededId", 
            type: "GET",
    ....
```

Tienes dos formas de añadir el parámetro:

```
...
url : "/urlDeController/" + id,
...
```

o también usando un *string template*, pero esto es posible que sea más complicado hacerlo funcionar porque entra en conflicto con la sintaxis de Thymeleaf y tendrás que *escaparlo*:

```
...
url : `/urlDeController/${id}`,
...
```

Por otro lado, veo que tienes

```
th:onclick="método('[[(${id})]]')"
```

si id es un número (supongamos que es 8), esto te va a generar:

```
th:onclick="método('[[(8)]]')"
```

con lo que tu método Javascript va a recibir un string `'[[(8)]]'`, generando la URL `/urlDeController/[[(8)]]`, que creo que no es lo que quieres, ya que quieres recibir un `int`. Creo que lo correcto sería

```
th:onclick="método(${id})"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Lo único que no doy con cómo tengo que pasar el id del método para que lo coja bien, de esta última manera tampoco funciona... ``` th:onclick="método(${id})" ``` . Si alguien puede ayudarme!!!!

Comment: Puedes comprobar qué HTML se genera en el cliente? Es decir, mira qué aparece en el onclick de ese botón